# Can I use "afoot" instead of "on foot" here? "I will go to market on foot."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverb-position

Can I use "afoot" instead of "on foot" in the sentence below ?

> I will go to market on foot.

Comment: Certainly. But you'll probably get some strange looks; even Sherlock seems to have stopped using it.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably be misunderstood, because "afoot" is more commonly used to mean, as Chambers dictionary puts it "actively in existence".

The original sense of "on foot" dates from Saxon England. However from the seventeenth century it has been idiomatic for "actively in existence". And that (in Britain at least) has been its principle meaning in my lifetime.(ed. WS2). It is OED sense 3.

> 3. In or into active existence, operation, or employment; in or into public circulation or currency; in or into preparation or progress.
>
> ?1585   E. Aggas tr. E. de L'Allouette Catholicke Apologie ii. xvii.
> f. 57v   Such as iniustly do pretend to set thereinto [sc. into the
> question of a king's right to choose his successor] a foote, haue made
> a League which they entitle Holy..wherwith to come into the hart of
> the Realme.

1656   R. Sanderson 20 Serm. 160   Pride..setteth

> contentions a foot at the first, and afterwards keepeth them afoot.
>
> 1665   D. Coxe Let. 6 Nov. in R. Boyle Corr. (2001) II. 578   From a
> Child of 14 or 15 yeares old I have been possessed with a strong
> persuasion that some of my Endeavours should prove Conducive to
> promote that Grand designe which of late yeares hath been set afoot
> sc: of writing a Hystory of Nature and giving a Mechanicall Solution
> of all the perticular Phenomena therein.

1680   in Hist. & Proc. House

> of Commons (1742) II. 46   And was not the Execution of the Laws put
> afoot..by that great Papist Clifford, who had then the greatest Share
> (under his Majesty) in the Administration of the Government?

1701   J.

> Somers Jura Populi Anglicani 29   They must set afoot Factions and
> Brigues.

1766   H. Vansittart Narr. Trans. Bengal 1760–4 II. 163   The

> Nabob having set afoot an expedition against Beteea and Napaul, which
> he intended to command in person, waited only my taking leave of him
> to set out.

1829   Scott Anne of Geierstein III. ix. 263   He..has in

> a right godly manner tried to set afoot a treaty of peace with my own
> father.

1872   A. W. Ward tr. E. Curtius Hist. Greece (new ed.) IV.

> vi. i. 362   But why should the Spartans have set this story afoot?
>
> 1929   Amer. Mercury Jan. 3/1   They have set afoot multi-membered
> clubs and associations that boast of gigantic material resources.

1963

> G. Heyer False Colours vi. 88   Who set the rumour afoot, I wonder?
>
> 2009   R. Cotton Riders from Long Pines ix. 106   ‘Do you want to hear
> what I've got afoot here?’.. ‘Or is this about as far as you ever
> planned on going in life?’

Comment: Yes. Good answer. But I think you could add an example or two e.g. "Plans are afoot to change the rules".

Answer (score 1):

***[Afoot](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/afoot)*** in the sense of ***walking*** is less commonly used than ***on foot*** See [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going%20on%20foot%2Cgoing%20%20afoot&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20on%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20afoot%3B%2Cc0)

> - "they went to the village afoot"; "quail are hunted either afoot or on horseback"
> - “she was afoot when I saw her this morning"

(The Free Dictionary)

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/afoot) suggests it is an AmE usage:

> North American predicative On foot.
>
> - ‘they were forced to go afoot’

Comment: It feels like a consciously old-fashioned usage to me (BrE), so I don't recommend that you use it in ordinary conversation.

Comment: @KateBunting  - Yes, more literary now I’d say.

Comment: "afoot" in the US is mostly isolated to regional dialects. It would be very unusual to hear **afoot** on US national network TV news, for example. You might hear it out in the western states where hunters and ranchers still ride horses.  "Were you afoot or on horseback?"